# CSS3 transform property on TideSDK Mac

Tags: macos, css, css-transitions, tidesdk

I'm building an application that I would want to run on both mac and windows. I'm using CSS3 for the styling and the UI of this application. I'm using selector:hover {transform : scale(1.5,1.5)} for certain images of my app and this works absolutely fine on windows but when i try to create the same hover effects on tide sdk mac I don't get the proper CSS3 effects. Does anyone know the reason for this? why something that works perfectly fine on the windows doesn't work on the mac version of tide sdk? Is it because they use different web-kit or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right ! the webkit implementation on windows linux and osx are totally different.

1) windows: we use WinCairo port of webkit.
2) Linux: we use GTK version of webkit.
3) osx: we use safari version (native) of webkit.

Along with that the webkit within TideSDK is ~2+ years old. These would be the reasons that you are getting slightly different behavior in different platforms.

Comment: Thanks, Mital!! I know the Tide SDK team is working on bringing up a new release with new webkit, but can you tell me when would the estimated date of the release be? The CSS3 transitions on osx version are worse and I dont want to stop using tidesdk because I cannot render the transitions I want :/

Comment: @Siva We are making a couple of posts on development progresa and making site changes to move to a new host. Hoping the updates will be up later this weekend. Blog will be updated along with the changes.